# How to properly save excel file, which was generated using c#?

Tags: c#, excel

So I use standard interface.

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

// file save function

```
 xlWorkBook.SaveAs("Bar Charts.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
 xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
 xlApp.Quit();
```

Everything is fine, but file appears here `C:\Users\Dex\Documents`. How can I change file destination true way? Don't want to move it after all.

Function described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx, but there is no such parameter.

Comment: Provide the fully qualified path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(@"YourPath" + "\Bar Charts.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
 xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
 xlApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 5):

The link you provided contains the answer:

> `Filename`
>
> The name of the file to be saved. You can include a full path; if you do not, Microsoft Office Excel saves the file in the current folder.

Use `@"C:\Another\Folder\Bar Charts.xls"` instead of just `"Bar Charts.xls"`. You can also use the [`Path.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you already have your folder in another string:

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(Path.Combine(folder, "Bar Charts.xls"), ...
```